# $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue iff spectral measure of $\lambda$ is nonzero

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $M$ be a normal operator on a Hilbert space and let $E$ be the spectral measure of $\sigma(M)$ (the spectrum of $M$). Show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue to $M$ $\iff E(\{\lambda\})\not = 0$.

Hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator $M$ can be written as $\int_{\sigma}\lambda dE(\lambda)$. Using properties to the spectral measure,
$$
             ME\{\mu\}=\int_{\sigma}\lambda dE(\lambda)E\{\mu\}=\int_{\sigma\cap\{\mu\}}\lambda dE(\lambda)=\mu E\{\mu\}, \\
                E\{\mu\}(M-\mu I)=(M-\mu I)E\{\mu\} =0.
$$
If $E\{\mu\} \ne 0$, then $\mathcal{N}(M-\mu I)\ne \{0\}$.

Conversely, suppose $Mx=\mu x$ for some $x\ne 0$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, define
$$
              S_{\epsilon} = \{ \lambda\in\mathbb{C} : |\lambda-\mu| \ge \epsilon \}.
$$
Then $0=E(S_{\epsilon})(M-\mu I)x=(M-\mu I)E(S_{\epsilon})x$ forces $E(S_{\epsilon})x=0$ because
\begin{align}
   0 &= \|(M-\mu I)E(S_{\epsilon})x\|^2 \\
    & = \int_{|\lambda-\mu|\ge\epsilon}|\lambda-\mu|^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 \\
    & \ge \int_{|\lambda-\mu|\ge\epsilon}\epsilon^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 \\
    & =\epsilon^2 \|E(S_{\epsilon})x\|^2.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
        \int_{|\lambda-\mu|> 0}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\int_{S_{\epsilon}}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 = 0.
$$
Hence,
$$
          E\{\mu\}x = E\{\mu\}x+E\{\lambda :|\lambda-\mu|>0\}x=x.
$$
Therefore, if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $E\{\mu\} \ne 0$.

Comment: How did you get $\|(M-\mu I)E(S_{\epsilon})x\|^2 = \int_{|\lambda-\mu|\ge\epsilon}|\lambda-\mu|^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 $ ? And also, why is $E\{\mu\}x=x$ ? @TrialAndError

Comment: $(M-\mu I)=\int (\lambda-\mu)dE(\lambda)$, $\int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)E(S)=\int_{S}f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)$, and $\|\int_{S}f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x\|^2=\int_{S}|f(\lambda)|^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2$. I was proving to you that $E\{\mu\}x = x$ if $Mx=\mu x$, which followed from the previous steps.

Comment: Is your definition of $S$ correct? Else Im not sure how the domain of integration can be $S$ in your latest comment. shouldnt it be $S \cap \sigma$?. Maybe $S$ should be the set $\{ \lambda \in \sigma(M) : |\lambda - \mu|>\epsilon\}$. @TrialAndError

Comment: @Ingvar : What I've stated as true in the above comment holds for any Borel subset $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What I meant was the set $S_\epsilon$ in you answer above (sorry for my ambiguity). It should be a subset of $\sigma(M)$. Now I got it, thank you.